# dojo: application header/footer bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I'm trying to replicate the "application header/footer" bar described in the documentation here:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/ScrollableView.html

The doc says:

> To make a bar widget (Heading, TabBar, or perhaps your custom bar widget) >fixed-positioned,
>
> 1. Place it outside ScrollableView
> 2. Add fixed:”top” for a header bar, or fixed:”bottom” for a footer bar

Here I copied/pasted the example:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>

<div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
  <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/RoundRect">
    <form data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/FormLayout" data-dojo-props="columns: 'single'">
      <div>
        <label>
          <strong>Username</strong>
        </label>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="text" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TextBox">
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label><strong>Password</strong>
        </label>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="password" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TextBox">
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <input id="btnLogin" type="submit" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" value="Login" class="mblBlueButton">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/SimpleDialog">
    <div class="mblSimpleDialogTitle">Title</div>
    <div class="mblSimpleDialogText">Text</div>
    <button data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" data-dojo-props="label:'Ok'"></button>
  </div>
</div>
<h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading" data-dojo-props='fixed:"bottom"'>Application Footer Bar</h1>
```

But as you can see it's quite different from the same example on the doc page. I'm talking about the footer bar should be positioned at the bottom of the page, not at the end of the view.

They don't say anything about any custom css rule, hence I'm wondering what I'm missing here.

### UPDATE

After applying the theme to the snippet, I was able to reproduce the actual (wrong) behavior as in my original code:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>

<div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
  <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/RoundRect">
    <form data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/FormLayout" data-dojo-props="columns: 'single'">
      <div>
        <label>
          <strong>Username</strong>
        </label>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="text" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TextBox">
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label><strong>Password</strong>
        </label>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="password" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TextBox">
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <input id="btnLogin" type="submit" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" value="Login" class="mblBlueButton">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/SimpleDialog">
    <div class="mblSimpleDialogTitle">Title</div>
    <div class="mblSimpleDialogText">Text</div>
    <button data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" data-dojo-props="label:'Ok'"></button>
  </div>
</div>
<h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading" data-dojo-props='fixed:"bottom"'>Application Footer Bar</h1>
```

If you go full page you will see the "Application Footer Bar" floating just below the content end, instead of staying fixed at the bottom of the page, as per the previous snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Check below example -

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>

<h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading" data-dojo-props='fixed:"top"'>Application Header Bar</h1>
<div id="view1" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollableView">
  View1
</div>
<div id="view2" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollableView">
  View2
</div>
<h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading" data-dojo-props='fixed:"bottom"'>Application Footer Bar</h1>
```

Hope this will help you (y).

Comment: This helps, because I wasn't aware the positioning logics were embedded into the themes! In my actual application the theme is set, but the behavior is the same as before. I'm trying to find the differences between the basic example.

Comment: I've just update the question with a snippet that reproduce the same wrong behavior of my actual code.